# Android Wheel control slide up animation on button click

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following android Layout

```
<TableRow style="@style/KeyboardRow" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/from_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        style="@style/TableLayoutSpilt"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_header"
            style="@style/SmallText"
            android:text="Click to select Three different Numbers" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_city"
            style="@style/BiggerText"
            android:text="Selected Numbers are" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow style="@style/KeyboardRow" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/traveller_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip" >

        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
            android:id="@+id/adults"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
            android:id="@+id/childs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
            android:id="@+id/infants"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_flight_booking_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corners"
            android:text="@string/searchflights"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

In the above layout i have three spinners which is created using http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/.

Initially Linear Layout "traveller_spinner" visibility is set to GONE.

I want to make slide up animation of "traveller_spinner" layout which has all three spinners on button click event.